# Reduce the Number of DOM Elements on dynamic website

Tags: html, dom, dynamic

I read around that having a lot of dom elements is bad. I tried to play around and remove as many thing as I could but I am still at 900.

My page loads dynamic data from the database which is submitted by users. If I want to display 100 rows, I get a higher number of dom elements.
Is there any way I can display all the rows without negatively impacting the dom count?

Comment: can you post your sample code please

Comment: it's just a foreach that retrieves data from the database and puts in in a div each time it finds a record